# How to use facebook api call in meteorjs to load bio into user profile?

Tags: mongodb, facebook-graph-api, meteor, atmosphere.js

I am trying learn how to add facebook data to my meteorjs project, so I can automatically fill in most user details such as bio. I have successfully got permissions to work and registered it as a test on facebook with localhost:3000 as domain/url. On the server side I have this:

```
 ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
            service: 'facebook'
        });

        ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
            service: 'facebook',
            appId: '11111111111111',
            secret: '11111111111111111'
        });
      });



Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {

options.profile = {};

options.profile.first = user.services.facebook.first_name;  
options.profile.last = user.services.facebook.last_name;
options.profile.relationship_status = user.services.facebook.relationship_status;
options.profile.religon = user.services.facebook.religon;

options.profile.quotes = user.services.facebook.quotes;

options.profile.city = user.services.facebook.location.city;

options.profile.cellnumber = "";

options.profile.bio = user.services.facebook.bio;
options.profile.university = user.services.facebook.education.school.name;
options.profile.faculty = user.services.facebook.education.concentration.name;
options.profile.graduation = user.services.facebook.education.year.name;


user.profile = options.profile;


return user;

});
```

Facebook Permissions:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
  requestPermissions: {
     facebook: ['user_friends', 'user_about_me', 'user_education_history', 
                'user_relationships','user_actions.fitness', 'user_actions.music','user_birthday',
                'user_location','user_likes', 'user_photos', 'user_relationship_details','user_religion_politics',
                 'user_work_history','publish_actions','rsvp_event', 'public_profile']
  }
});
```

How do I use FB api call to load FB bio into the user creation function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some examples in the s-id package: http://s-id.meteor.com/

For example:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
    if (user.services.facebook) {

        user.username = user.services.facebook.email;
        user.emails = [];
        user.emails.push({
            address: user.services.facebook.email,
            verified: true
        });

        return user;
    }
    return user;
}
```

So if there is a user.service.facebook.bio you can take it and place it on your user.bio field like:

```
user.bio = user.services.facebook.bio;
```

Comment: When trying to get access to user bio, I get undefined value. Is this because I need an access token or are client based permissions and appId + secret enough?

Comment: I think facebook needs permistion for bio : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-extended-profile but I am not sure :/ 
You can try to ask for it. See here: https://github.com/juliancwirko/meteor-s-id/blob/master/client/sIdSocialButtons.js#L7 You should add 'user_about_me' to the 'requestPermisions' array. But unfortunately I havn't tested it. So i hope this is the case.

Comment: I have already made that permission. However no other info is being sent other than first name and last. Only public info is available. The popup Authentication is successful with permissions listed (including user_about_me) then accepted by user.

Comment: hmmmm have you checked if there is a field named 'bio' for sure? Maybe it is some other name for this in user.services.facebook. You can always console.log the user.services.facebook object and check it out. There is also something like 'facebook review' : "If your app requests this permission Facebook will have to review how your app uses it." https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#requirereview This also could be a blocker.  I think this is something new. I need to play with this too :)